# python selenium: how to upload file with a href link popup

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I wanna upload a file on a website using selenium (python), it has a href link, a folder popup window appeared (my local environment folder window) when the link clicked, here is the web html source code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="text-decoration:underline" onclick="UploadClick(this)">click to upload</a>
```

I tried to locate this link and click and using `send_keys(file_path)` function:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "xxxxx".click()
driver.send_keys(file_path)
```

and got the error like this:

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

Can you please help me to figure it out? Many THX!

Comment: you have to find element to send text - `driver.find_element(...).send_keys()`. But you can't do this with standard `Folder Window`. You should rather find `<input type="file">` and send keys directly to this element without opening `Folder Window`

Comment: @furas thanks for your help! I have already resolved my problem!

Comment: you could put your solution as answer below and mark your answer as accepted. And later you may upvote your answer.